# Identify the array of arrays in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have built some code from a tutorial I found in a book. It works and I am able to display my data from CoreData successfully in a tableView. I now want to identify the data/object that the fetchRequest returns. I feel like such a dummy because I cannot understand the syntax enough to isolate my object containing my array of data. This is a snippet of the code which I am having difficulty understanding:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sessions" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //NSLog(@"Entity is set to: %@", entity);
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"refid" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Sessions *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Format cell data ready to be displayed
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, dd LLL yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:info.date];

    NSNumber *dist1Nbr = info.dist1;
    int dist1Int = [dist1Nbr integerValue];
    float distIntKorM = ([dist1Nbr integerValue])/1000;
    NSString *dist1StrMeters = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", dist1Int];
    NSString *dist1StrKorM = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.01f", distIntKorM];


    //Select image to display
    if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Run"]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trainers-15x10.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@", info.sessiontype, dist1StrKorM];
    } else if ([info.sport isEqualToString:@"Other"]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"weights-15x10.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: (%@),", dateString, info.sport];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Type: %@,  Dist: %@", info.sessiontype, dist1StrKorM];
    } 

}
```

If anyone can help me it would be massively appreciated.

Comment: what you do not understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access an array of `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` objects by calling:

```
NSArray *sections = _fetchedResultsController.sections;
```

Each of these objects represents a section in your table. For a given section, you can do something like:

```
id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>section = sections[0];
NSArray *objects = section.objects;
```

to access the managed objects in that section. Or, if you've got an index path, you can access the associated object directly by doing:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

On in reverse:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:object];
```

Is this what you're looking for?

**update**

Forgot this one. As Juan suggested below, you can access all fetched objects with:

```
NSArray *allObjects = _fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code you posted the NSFetchedresultsController is going to return all objects of class Sessions ordered descending by key 'refid'. NSFetchedResultsCOntroller is used together with a UITableViewController to display the results of a fetch request to the Core Data storage.

However if you want just to obtain all the objects in a array without using the table view you could do the following, for example in viewWillAppear:

```
if (self.managedObjectContext) {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Sessions"];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"refid" ascending:NO];
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performfetch];
    NSArray *results = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]; // an array of Sessions objects ordered descending by refid key
    for (Sessions *sessions in results) {
        NSLog(@"Sessions = %@", sessions);
    }
}
```

You have to make sure that the NSManagedContext is properly initialized before or nothing will be displayed.